# Returning multiple sets of data using JSON with Java and JQuery

Tags: java, jquery, json

I want to send sets of data from servlet to the jsp using JSON. To elaborate, what exactly I want to do is take multiple rows from the database and print their values in jsp. I done with the part of DB connectivity and fetching of data. But I could not find a way to forward them to jsp using JSONObject. Each row has multiple attributes(column values). Please help me solve the problem.

What I'm doing is:

```
Collection <JsonObject> c=new ArrayList();
JsonObject j[] = null;  

for(int i=0;i<uid_list.size();i++){//uid_list contains all the user_id's from the database
               j[i].add("uid", j[i]);
               j[i].add("fname", j[i]);
               j[i].add("lname", j[i]);
               j[i].addProperty("uid", uid_list.get(i).toString());
               j[i].addProperty("fname", fname_list.get(i).toString());
               j[i].addProperty("lname", lname_list.get(i).toString());
               c.add(j[i]);
}
```

Also, is there any difference between JsonObject and JSONObject? The latter could not be recognized in servlet and by using JsonObject the put method is not recognized.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of confusion here. **Servlet** - server side request processor, **JSP** - a servlet that is written in JSP mark-up, also server side. **HTML** - client side mark up rendered by JSP to display structured data, **JavaScript** - client side language to make display dynamic. Now, _where_ are you trying to send your JSON, to the **JSP** or the **HTML**?

Comment: @bmorris591- I'm trying to send JSON to the JSP.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from your code trying to insert into an uninitialized array, there are many JSON library for Java. You need to provide more details which one you're using

Also if your objective is just passing the JSON string into the browser, you might not even need jsp, you can just write the string version of the JSON object directly into the HttpResponse

Comment: I'm using google-gson library. And I want all the data to b displayed and that data can be quite large.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the JspnObject array has to be instantiated before it is used. Therefore, this means the following:

```
JsonObject j[] = new JsonObject[noOfObjects to be iterated]
```

Comment: Thanks I got the point. Can you please tell me how to send this ArrayList of JsonObjects to the JSP and parse it there?